# autocomplete bash v3 on personal script

Tags: bash, macos, unix

I have a script on bash -v 3 like this:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Menu di esempio
menu() {
    case $1 in
        frontend)
            echo "Updating frontend"
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Invalid option. Try again."
            ;;
    esac
}

# Esegui il menu
while true; do
    read -p "Type an option: " input # I wish to have autocompletition here
    menu "$input"
done
```

I wish to insert the autocompletition as I have on standard terminal on macOs.

is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-e` to enable readline in bash's `read` but it will autocomplete filenames and command lines, therefore you may need to simulate the options as files.

```
#! /bin/bash


autocomplete_input() {
    local -r opts=( "$@" )
    (
        readonly temp=$(mktemp -d /tmp/myreadline.XXXX)
        cd "$temp"
        trap "rm -rf $temp" EXIT
        touch "${opts[@]}"
        read -e -p "Type an option: " input # I wish to have autocompletition here
        printf '%s\n' "$input"
    )
}

input=$(autocomplete_input "frontend" "other option" "quit")
```

Then when `input` is being read you can type, for example `f+TAB` and it will be autocomplete to `frontend` and so on.